# Changing position of two separate numbers in column names delineated by hyphens

Tags: r

I have column names that follow the pattern "Data_sum-[single digit number]-[1 or 2 digit number]".

```
Current format: Data_sum-1-9 , Data_sum-1-10, ... Data_sum-2-9, Data_sum-2-10
```

But I am trying to swap position of the two numbers

```
Desired format: Data_sum-9-1 , Data_sum-10-1, ... Data_sum-10-2, Data_sum-10-2
```

This is the code I've been playing around with in R but so far can't get it to recognize the two different numeric groupings

```
sub("[[\\\d]]-(\\\d{1,2})+", "\\\2\\\1", colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you mark your first group in regex with `[]` instead of `()`, try with:

```r
df <- data.frame(`Data_sum-1-9` = NA , 
                 `Data_sum-1-10` = NA,
                 check.names = FALSE)
df
#>   Data_sum-1-9 Data_sum-1-10
#> 1           NA            NA
colnames(df) <- sub("-(\\d)-(\\d+)$", "-\\2-\\1", colnames(df))
df
#>   Data_sum-9-1 Data_sum-10-1
#> 1           NA            NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Better use `"-(\\d+)-(\\d+)$"` if first number also had more than one digit.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably smarter ways, but:

```
custom_rename <- function (x) {
  pieces <- unlist(strsplit(x, "-"))
  paste(pieces[[1]],pieces[[3]],pieces[[2]],sep="-")
}

df <- data.frame("Data_sum-2-9" = 1, "Blah_blah-20-4" = 1, check.names=F)
colnames(df) <- lapply(colnames(df), custom_rename)
```

Output:

```
> df
  Data_sum-9-2 Blah_blah-4-20
1            1              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using three capture groups (and raw strings).

```
> sub(r'{(\d+)(-)(\d+)$}', '\\3\\2\\1', x)
[1] "Data_sum-9-1"    "Data_sum-10-1"   "Data_sum-1-10"   "Data_sum-100-11" "foo"
```

---

*Data:*

```
> x <- c('Data_sum-1-9', 'Data_sum-1-10', 'Data_sum-10-1', 'Data_sum-11-100', 'foo')
```